# Vue not reacting to data change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following vue2 code

```
methods: {
    open: function(conversation){
        conversation.loading = true;
        this.$set(this, 'activeConversation', conversation);
        this.$http.get('/conversation/messages', {
            params: {
                conversationId: conversation.id
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            // this.$set(this.activeConversation, 'messages', response.data); // this was the first try
            this.activeConversation.messages.push(response.data[0]); // this is the second try
        })
    }
}
```

The template reacts to the first $set when i change the activeConversation. But when I change the messages property of the activeConversation nothing happens.
I see the changes in vue devtools, but nothing changes in the DOM.

By nothing changes, I mean the v-for="message in activeConversation.messages" does not render anything. nor does the {{activeConversation}}

in data i have activeConversation: null. As a conversation i pass an object with id, sender, messages

Comment: Does `activeConversation` property has `messages` property in your `data()` method of the component? If not, add it there and try again. Other than that, you can directly set the properties instead of calling `$set`.

Comment: have you a `key` in your `v-for` like this `v-for="message in activeConversation.messages" :key="message"` ?

Comment: no.. activeConversation = null bydefault

Comment: Could you give us more code - your data model, also tell us what you pass as conversation into the open method ? Is it string, array, object ?

Comment: edited response

Comment: Okay, and how your response from server looks like ? Could you try to change this `this.$set(this.activeConversation, 'messages', response.data);`, to this `this.$set(this.activeConversation, 'messages', response.data.json());` or even this `this.$set(this.activeConversation, 'messages', response.json());`

Comment: response.data is an array of objects. the response data is pre-parsed

Comment: Are you sure that is pre-parsed ? I tested your example here and it's suposed to work http://jsbin.com/jumuselole/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes.. i am logging it and is an array, not a string or anything else

Comment: This is very annoying.. I am adding messages via devtools and they are not rendering

Comment: If you want I could try to help you on teamviewer, because this code you posted should work properly.

Comment: add me on skype please ionut.capraru2